# How to monitor the data changes of the parent component in the child component

Tags: vue.js

When the data of the parent component changes, how to realize real-time monitoring and respond in the child component.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425633/how-to-send-updated-values-from-parent-component-to-child-component-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can watch props when props changes:

```
<div id="app">
  <childcomponent :myprop="text"></childcomponent>
  <button @click="text = 'New text'">Change text</button>
</div>
```

Watch for changes in ChildComponent using watch method!

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'This is Text'
  },
  components: {
    'childcomponent' : {
     template: `<p>{{ myprop }}</p>`,
     props: ['myprop'],
     watch: { 
      myprop: function(newValue, oldValue) { 
       console.log('Prop changed and new value is: ', newVal, ' | old value: ', oldValue);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Answer (score 0):

```
props: ["opType", "editData"],
watch: {
  editData: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (this.editData.pryType === "MOBN") {
        this.infoIndex = 0;
      } else if (this.editData.pryType === "EMAL") {
        this.infoIndex = 1;
      } else if (this.editData.pryType === "SVID") {
        this.infoIndex = 2;
      } else if (this.editData.pryType === "BBIN") {
        this.infoIndex = 3;
        if (this.getListSeconed) {
          this.getkList();
          this.getListSeconed = false;
        }
      }
    },
    deep: true
  }
},
```

Can try like this.